# Product image on top of the other

Tags: css, list, image, product, overlay

I have 2 product images that on phone go one on top of the other at the sides. How can I make them to fit properly ?

```
<div class="col-md-6 background-hard-case" style="padding: 39px 19px 24px; margin: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
      <div class="row clearfix groupedCaseList" id="groupedCaseList" data-limit="2" data-typeid="1347">
          Loading GIF
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix soft-case-content" style="padding: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: 39px 0px 24px 19px; margin: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
      <div class="row clearfix groupedCaseList" id="groupedCaseList" data-limit="2" data-typeid="1325">
          Loading GIF
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are no images in your code

Comment: I'm assuming these images are set using `background-image` using one of your classes. Either way it's kind of unclear what you're asking exactly. Please post some code that reproduces the problem.